# Multiple powershell scripts outputting to the same text file

Tags: powershell

I have a set of ps scripts, i will call them parents, that invoke other ps scripts, i will call them children.  They all need to write to the same text file, i will call **myoutfile.txt**.  The first output of the parent script should clear **myoutputfile.txt**.  All subsequent child ps scripts should append to **myoutputfile.txt**, including another parent script later in the logic.

Using `Out-File`, the parent PS script opens and locks the file **myoutputfile.txt**.  The children PS scripts need append to append to the file, but because the parent created the text file the children PS scripts fail silently to append to the text file.

I have tried Out-File and `Add-Content`.  `Add-Content` puts out Chinese to the text file.

Comment: You can use Mutexes... see here for a [detailed](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/) example...

Answer (score 1):

Either Out-File with append or Add-Content would work.
Unless you are actually trying to write Chinese, [the encoding could be wrong.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/add-content-for-filesystem)

```
$File ="PathTo\test.txt"
Get-Date | Out-File $File -Encoding ascii
"TEXT" | Out-File $File -Append -Encoding utf32
Add-Content -Path $File -Value "END" -Encoding Unicode
```

As you can see in the file, the result varies depending on encoding. 
If you're getting Chinese, my guess is bytes.
Likely conversion problems earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

It took a combo of Peter Schneider's comment and Martin van Delft's answer to get it working.